# How RCS can be used with botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework, rich-communications-services

We do some bot development for **channels** like Skype, Messenger etc.
The framework we use is https://dev.botframework.com/.

We were trying to figure out how [RCS](http://www.gsma.com/network2020/rcs-2/) can be used as **channel** for bots?

Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally worked with RCS, but you should be able to write a layer into your application between RCS and a bot exposed via the Direct Line channel, using the Direct Line API: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle  RCS wouldn't be a full fledged channel, perse.  But, the experience could be the same to the end user as if it were.

Please refer to this FAQ related to your question: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/faq#i-have-a-communication-channel-id-like-to-be-configurable-with-bot-framework-can-i-work-with-microsoft-to-do-that

> **I have a communication channel I’d like to be configurable with Bot Framework. Can I work with Microsoft to do that?**
>
> We have not provided a general mechanism for developers to add new
>   channels to Bot Framework, but you can connect your bot to your app
>   via the Direct Line API. If you are a developer of a communication
>   channel and would like to work with us to enable your channel in the
>   Bot Framework we’d love to hear from you.

Comment: Is there any one providing RCS implementation services?

Comment: I haven't heard.  You could email them and ask: info@gsma.com